# How to implement conditional compilation without messing up the library API?

Tags: c++, cmake, api-design, conditional-compilation

I have a library which can do GPU computation using the OpenCL framework. Sadly, OpenCL is not available on all platforms. However I would still like to be able to compile my code on those platforms, just excluding OpenCL functionality.

I think this question applies to all situations where you want to conditionally compile some external resource which may not always be available, and it messes with your library API.

Currently I have it set up like this:

**CMake:**

```
if(ENABLE_OPENCL)
    add_definitions(-DENABLE_OPEN_CL)
    find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(mylibrary ${OpenCL_LIBRARY})
endif()
```

**C++**

```cpp
// settings.hpp, exposed to public API
class settings
{
    int general_setting_1;
    bool general_setting_2;
    // ... Other general settings
#ifdef ENABLE_OPEN_CL
    int open_cl_platform_id;
    // ... Other settings available only when OpenCL is available
#endif
    // More settings, possibly also conditionally compiled on other external libraries
};
```

```cpp
// computation.cpp, internal to the library

#ifdef ENABLE_OPEN_CL
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#endif

void do_things()
{
    // ... 

#ifdef ENABLE_OPEN_CL
    if(settings.open_cl_platform_id != -1)
    {
        // Call OpenCL code
    }
#endif

    // ...
}
```

So when I compile the library, if I want to enable OpenCL I do `cmake .. -DENABLE_OPEN_CL`.

This works, but if the client is consuming the library compiled with `ENABLE_OPEN_CL`, it forces the client to define the same `ENABLE_OPEN_CL`, otherwise the included library's header file don't match the one used in the client, and very bad things happen.

This opens a whole can of worms, for example what if the client forgets to do it? What if it uses the same identifier name for something else?

Can I avoid this? If not, is there some way I could verify that the header files match on the client and the library, and cause a compilation error? Or at least throw a run-time exception? What is the correct approach to this scenario?

Comment: Have you considered dynamic loading and late binding ?

Comment: And could you make header to not depend on the ENABLE_OPEN_CL define? but in cpp when compiled without this flag - you provide an empty stub function implementation for any API - returning ERROR_NOTIMPLEMENTED - so client does not need to define anything - but if it is linked against library without OpenCL support any call dependingon it will fail (in well documented manner)?

Comment: Another approach would be to generate the header file (library_config.h) with all proper defines based on build settings and distribute this header with the library (including it in any public h-file you distribute) so that client does not need to add any defines to its own code

Comment: The canonical CMake thing to do is not to force the user to enable OpenCL on their build line, but have CMake do a test compile of a small OpenCL program to see if it works on that platform and then define `HAVE_OPENCL` or something similar to let your code know if OpenCL is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way to do it, is to leave `open_cl_platform_id` as a member of `settings` even if OpenCL is not supported.  The user then gets a run-time error if they try to use OpenCL functionality when the library hasn't been compiled for it.

Alternatively, have two header files `settings_no_open_cl.hpp` and `settings_open_cl.hpp`, and require the user to include the right one.

Comment: What I ended up doing is I left `open_cl_platform_id` in, as suggested. But I felt like that left the API not explicit enough, so I also added another setting `bool use_open_cl`, which must be set to true to explicitly show intent to use that functionality. I then throw an exception if `use_open_cl` is true, but `ENABLE_OPEN_CL` is not defined.